# WKWebView can't load some pictures

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a strange problem.

My Html String contains

```
<p>
    <img src="http://img.qdaily.com/article/article_show/20181220221726s0BIHSdN42kfbKqT.jpg?imageMogr2/auto-orient/thumbnail/!640x380r/gravity/Center/crop/640x380/quality/85/format/jpg/ignore-error/1" alt="">
</p>
```

**I use WKWebView to load it but failed.**

[image: screen shot]

**When I click the link in the img tag, It shows that it can't load the resource.**

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Does the image load if you load it in the browser?

Comment: @Scriptable Yes.

Answer (score -1):

Follow Steps

1) Allow NSAppTransportSecurity into Plist File.

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

2) `import WebKit`

3) Create `@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!`

4) In ViewDidLoad write this code

```
 let imgUrl = "http://img.qdaily.com/article/article_show/20181220221726s0BIHSdN42kfbKqT.jpg?imageMogr2/auto-orient/thumbnail/!640x380r/gravity/Center/crop/640x380/quality/85/format/jpg/ignore-error/1"
    let tempUrl = ""
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><p><img src=\(imgUrl) alt=\(tempUrl)></p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)

    }
```

Comment: @Scriptable check again with above code its working fine. I hope you will find out solution of query. !!